# Android N textAppearence not the same as Android M

Tags: java, android, textview

When using textAppearenceMedium and textAppearenceSmall in a widget on Android N the text color is black, but in Android M the text color is white/light grey. Is there any reason for this? I'm frustrated because now I will have to create a custom text style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the theme in styles file for each version this seems like an issue of white/black theme